# Creating an online palindrome

Tags: palindrome

I am trying to create an online palindrome sensor(The alphabet consists of 0,1,2,3,...9). The code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x=0;
int y=0;

int c;
int i=0;
while(1)
{
cin>>c;
//I keep a track of previous number in x and its reverse in y and use them to create the 
//the new number and reverse at every input. Then I compare x and y. If equal the number is
//a palindrome.
/*eg:(When 121 is entered digit by digit)
  i=0:-
  x=10*0+1    y=0+ 10^0 *1 

  i=1:-
  x=10*1+2    y=1+ 10^1 *2

  i=2:-
  x=10*12+1   y=21+ 10^2 *1
*/
x=10*x+c;
y=y+ static_cast<int>(pow(10.0,static_cast<double>(i)) *c);
cout<<"y= "<<y<<" and "<<"x= "<<x<<endl;
if(y==x)
cout<<"Palindrome"<<endl;

i++;
}    

return 0;
}
```

First, I enter 1 and it was indicated as palindrome(as expected). Then, I entered 2 and nothing happened(as expected, `'y= 21 and x= 12'` was printed). But, then I again entered 1 and this time too nothing happened(**not as expected**) and this was printed:

```
y= 120 and x= 121
```

Can anyone tell me, how did y become 120 when it was supposed to be 121?

Comment: why are you raising this to a power?

Comment: @Woot4Moo...Because that is how it works...121= 10^2 *1+21

Answer (score 1):

You are doing far too much math:

```
public static boolean isPalindrom(char[] word){
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = word.length - 1;
    while (i2 > i1) {
        if (word[i1] != word[i2]) {
            return false;
        }
        ++i1;
        --i2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

All you need to do is fill an array with values as the user enters them and invoke a function similar to this.  The use of exponents is a colossal waste of resources when simpler solutions exist.

Comment: @Woot4Moo...I agree with you...But, I was asking what is wrong with my answer.How does y change from 21 to 20 after a loop? I updated the question for better understanding

Comment: @avinash not that it should matter but is this c or c++?  I want to recreate the program locally